# Oracle weblogic server missing libraries

Tags: java, oracle, jdeveloper, weblogic12c, oracle12c

I downloaded the oracle WebLogic Server 12c on my server and created a domain.  The weblogic server is up and running but when I enter the deployments section  it is empty , no libraries are installed .

When we create a local WebLogic Server in JDeveloper some basic libraries are installed and deployed by default on the server.  But in the case of a WebLogic Server installation alone on the server side the deployments section is empty and missing some key libraries like adf.oracle.domain(1.0,12.2.1.0.0) or adf.oracle.domain.webapp(1.0,12.2.1.0.0) .

Can anyone please tell me why the deployments section is empty ? Where I can find them to install (as my application does not run without the basic libraries being installed)?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/adf/administer/GUID-544B1F4B-64CC-4559-B0AE-F45086726A4F.htm#ADFAG20790

Comment: Because a vanilla WebLogic installation has no way to know you need the ADF libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDeveloper has its own embedded WLS instance, so you can test your app from inside the IDE. That's convenient.

But many enterprises use WLS for applications not built using ADF. WLS doesn't include every Java library that might possibly be used. Instead it requires you to install the additional libraries you need to run your app. As @GriffeyDog points out, [the steps are in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/concepts.htm#NETAG177).